# confounding htaccess errors leading to error code 500

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**SOLVED**

*Answer*:
OK. So I've figured it out. I'm using shared hosting and the host has suExec enabled. It won't allow files to have permissions other than default (755 for folders, 644 for files etc). It was a simple matter of changing the permissions and it started working just fine!

Thanks a lot for all of your help!

---

*Question*:

I apologise ahead for the long post. I have two directories - the main one and a subdirectory called cms. Here is the .htaccess code for the main directory

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (.*).php - [L,QSA]
RewriteRule (.*).gif - [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^cms$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$2 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/)?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)?$ index.php?page=home [L,QSA]
```

However, when I try to access something like

http://website.com/cms/index.php, I get a 500 Internal error. All the files in the directory have the right perms (I even tried 777 to no avail). I've also tried changing the order, no luck there too.

I've tried with different combos but haven't had any luck.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

PS. In case it wasn't clear enough, I'm very much a noob.

---

edit

OK. So I've found the error log and here is what I see under it:

```
[Tue Jun 14 16:29:19 2011] [error] [client 1.1.1.1] File does not exist: /home/user/public_html/main_dir/500.shtml
[Tue Jun 14 16:29:19 2011] [error] [client 1.1.1.1] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/user/public_html/main_folder/cms/index.php" is writeable by group
```

Does that yield any clues?

Comment: Did you try to read apache logs? There should be error message describing what's wrong.

Comment: 500 errors on an .htaccess file usually mean the htaccess file contains a directive which the server's configuration does not permit, meaning you need an AllowOverride somewhere to enable whatever the htaccess is trying to do.

Comment: @Ivan, I tried the following code and it didnt work. #RewriteLog "rewrite.log"
#RewriteLogLevel 3

Comment: @Marc, Its just simple redirection. This code (or somethingl ike it ) was working earlier. So I know there isn't an AllowOverride directive required.

Comment: `RewriteLog` is only allowed in server config, not in .htaccess. Try to find your error_log file (Mine is located in /var/log/httpd/error_log). I've tried your config with my server and it works without 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend setting Apache's RewriteLogLevel and checking logs for error.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel

Comment: I tried adding this code, but that broke the redirection that was working also. Am I doing something wrong?     #RewriteLog "rewrite.log"
#RewriteLogLevel 3

Comment: @Bouncer It says `Context: server config, virtual host` in the manual for both of those directives, so you can't use those in .htaccess but only in server configuration, my bad.